# Python Exchangelib.errors.ErrorTimeoutExpired

Tags: python, timeout, exchange-server

We have a python code that formats and converts information into a file which is then emailed to users through our internal exchange mail server. It has run without issue for several years now and we are planning some updates. Both the test build and the production build have now run into an error when sending emails.

`exchangelib.errors.ErrorTimeoutExpired: Raised from ReadTimeout (HTTPSConnectionPool (host='mail.internalserver.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=120)`

The code is also still running to near completion and successfully sending the emails despite the exception.

We were under the impression that this was due to the exchange servers now having enough resources to process the requests but are still seeing the error message pop up after some server restarts.

I've also written a very small code to send a smaller email with no attachment and that also sees the same exception raised. There were no changes made between successful runs of the code and the exception message being raised. I've checked and confirmed that the port is open and we are able to both send and receive emails.

This may be more of an exchange issue as well, however we have not made any changes on that end.

Answer (score 0):

After migrating the mailboxes to a different server the exception was no longer raised and everything worked as normal. Not really an answer to the cause but the item is resolved at this point.